# Three-way comparison operator member vs non-member implementation

Tags: c++, comparison-operators, c++20, spaceship-operator

Two-way comparison operators should be non-members functions if:

- you want the first operand to be of a type that is not this class
- you want implicit type conversion any of the two operands

The new C++20 three-way comparison operator has symmetric generation rules. The name lookup for an expression `a@b`, where `@` is a two-way comparison operator, is done in the order `a@b`, `a<=>b` and `b<=>a` (with this order of preference in case of ambiguity when selecting the best match from the overload resolution set). See [P0515R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r2.pdf) for details. This means the operator `<=>` can be a member function and still allow the first operand to not be of this class type.

The paper, however, contains this note:

> Normally, operator<=> should be just a member function; you will still
>   get conversions on each parameter because of the symmetric generation
>   rules in §2.3. In the rare case that you also want to support
>   conversions on both parameters at the same time (to enabling compare
>   two objects neither of which is of this type, but using this type’s
>   comparison function), make it a non-member friend.

If I understand this correctly it says non-member implementation should be only needed if implicit conversion on both operands at the same time is needed? Is that correct? Can I see an actual example when that is needed? I am thinking of this although it does not seem like a valid example:

```
struct foo
{
   foo(int const x) 
      : data{ x } {}
   foo(std::string_view x) 
      : data{std::stoi(x.data())}{}

   friend auto operator<=>(foo const & lhv, foo const & rhv) noexcept
   {
      return lhv.data <=> rhv.data;
   }

private:
   int data;
};


int main()
{
   assert(foo {42} == foo {"42"});        // OK
   assert(42 == std::string_view("42"));  // ??
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an illustrative (though not necessarily practical) example:

```
struct A {
    int i;
};

struct B {
    B(A a) : i(a.i) { }

    int i;
};

strong_ordering operator<=>(B const& lhs, B const& rhs) {
    return lhs.i <=> rhs.i;
}

A{2} == A{2}; // okay, true
A{2} < A{1};  // okay, false
```

We find the candidate taking two `B`s at global scope, and it's viable, so we convert both arguments and use it. If that operator was either a member function or a non-member `friend` declared within the class, name lookup wouldn't have found it.

---

Note that in the OP, `<=>` is declared as a non-member `friend` within the class. This means that name lookup would not find it for `42 == string_view("42")`, since neither of those arguments is a `foo`. You would need to add a normal non-member declaration to make it visible for such lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the example and the comment on the way operator<=> was declared. I changed the example to the actual intention.

Comment: @Marius Sorry, I reverted your edit. Please dont edit questions to invalidate answers. The question is fine as-is and it's important to highlight the issue.

Comment: `struct silly {silly(std::vector<silly> const& v):s(v.size()) {}; std::size_t s = -1; friend std::strong_ordering operator<=>(silly const& lhs, silly const& rhs) {return lhs.s <=> rhs.s;}};` -- even if neither argument is a `silly`, `std::vector<silly>{} <=> std::vector<silly>{}` still find the method and converts!

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont That's because a non-defaulted three-way comparison operator (`<=>`) does not generate other comparison operators.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Sorry I thought you used `==` for the example. You'd need to do partial template specialization for `std::vector<silly>`. https://godbolt.org/z/GjT8zhazc

Comment: Okay, the comment is pretty old. I think standard library back then did not implement `operator<=>` for `std::vector`. It works now https://godbolt.org/z/4xPfv1ejq