# Why are the lexicographical comparison operators assumed as non-member functions for containers?

Tags: c++, containers, std, member-functions, non-member-functions

When having a look at the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) of `std::map`, I noticed that the lexicographical comparison operators (between maps) were not counted as member functions. Checked a few other containers *(vector, list, etc.)* and saw the same situation for them also. Is there a reason for that? Aren't those operators overloaded inside those container classes?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421729/10400598) is a related answer arguing the basic rules of operator overloading.

Comment: Most operators can be overloaded either as member or as non-member functions. I'd say the latter are better, because they treat both arguments the same way (e.g. member ones don't allow implicit conversions for the lhs).

Comment: @KamilCuk It's not just about `std::map`. Even the `std::basic_string` implements those operators as non-member functions. I'm looking for the reason for that design choice.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the answer. Where would we need an implicit conversion for the `lhs` parameter? Is there another reason for the latter?

Comment: The example with the conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52938077/2752075 Though I wasn't able to do the same thing with standard containers. *"Is there another reason"* I don't know any.

Comment: @JaMiT I meant that the documentation classifies the methods according to their relations and operations. The lexicographical comparison operators are in a group called *non-member* functions.

Comment: Oh, you mean specifically what would be `std::map::operator<` and its friends. I had read that as the comparison operator of the keys.

Comment: Do you want *a* reason, or *the* reason? I don't know what the standards committee was thinking, but SO's go-to answer on the subject, [A: What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421729), does give the advice *"If a binary operator treats both operands equally (it leaves them unchanged), implement this operator as a non-member function"*, which applies here.

Comment: @JaMiT From what you've shared, I see that there isn't a single reason. Some best practices and limitations drive the designer to implement some of the operators as non-member functions. Now it is more clear for me, thanks for your time.